# Neo4j Spring Boot Actuator health and Unsupported authentication token, scheme 'none' is only allowed when auth is disabled

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-boot-actuator

Actuator health endpoint in my Spring boot application shows:

```
"org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Unsupported authentication token, scheme 'none' is only allowed when auth is disabled."
```

Neo4j is running, application is working properly. What may be wrong with Spring Boot Actuator?